# How can I make a stack of div's fixed until the 1 before it has completely left the browser window?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Really sorry about my poorly worded title but I don't know how to explain my question.

I am making myself a portfolio website which has 4 main sections, profile cover, bio, websites and photography. Currently I have each div stacked on top of one another in a basic website layout. Instead of having the user scroll down the page looking at each section as one long list I would like to make the page seem layered. Once the user has reached the end of section 1 for example section 2 has a fixed position until section 1 has completely left the browser window. The best example of what I'm trying to ask for has been done by [Vox Media](http://www.voxmedia.com/).

Here is some sample html and css so you get an idea of the properties:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
} 

.div1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding-top: 300px;
}

.div2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1800px;
    background-color: red;
    padding-top: 300px;
}

.div3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2400px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding-top: 300px;
}

.div4 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    padding-top: 300px;
}


<div class="div1"><h1>Profile Cover</h1></div>
<div class="div2"><h1>Bio</h1></div>
<div class="div3"><h1>Websites</h1></div>
<div class="div4"><h1>Photography</h1></div>
```

I haven't written any JS to go along with the HTML and CSS because I don't know what to type.

First time using this forum so I apologise if I have missed out on some settings or features to help you answer my question. Thanks in advance, Matt.

Comment: I'd go with [Bootstrap scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy).

Answer (score 3):

This [parallax scrolling tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/) may be helpful.

UPDATE: [Simple technique for Parallax Scrolling](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/)

[Demo](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/338_parallax/src/index.html), [Demo(simple technique)](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/2138_SimpleParallax/Demo/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you have in terms of styling is correct!  If you're using HTML5 be sure to give all parents of your div's a height of 100% or else this won't work.  In terms of layering all you would need to do is add a different background color to each of the div's to make the site look "sectioned."

Comment: Thanks but I meant I would like that scrolling effect they have done. Eg. div1 has a z-index: 4;, div2 z-index: 3;, div3 z-index: 2; and div4 z-index: 1; with fixed positioning until the previous div has left the screen when scrolling down. I imagine to have that effect I would need to add some js so the positioning changes property when the user scrolls so far?